# Ruby on rails - Accidentally removed a folder and got migrations issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rails-migrations

I accidentally removed a folder (it might be *db* or *lib* folder), but  immediately find out about it and put it back on same place it was (*I am using **RubyMine** so I did cmd+z (on Mac)*).

This caused so I got error: `Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run rake db:migrate` and I ran `rake db:migrate` and as I could see It ran all migrations files *(from first migration file)* and **migrated** all my tables as  it was newly added and removed all my records.

Since I have version control, I *rested the branch* to previous branch but still have the same issue.

I have doubled checked all the folders and files and everything is where is needs to be (*I think*) but for some reason it needs to run all migration once again.

I am currently in `Development ENV` and don't know if it is going to run `migration` when deployed with `capistrano gem` to `Production ENV` and remove all my records in my `Production ENV`.

In my `schema.rb` my version is: `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161108160645)` and `20161108160645` is the same number as my last migration file `20161108160645_add_name_avatar_to_comments.rb`

What can I do to fix everything back to normal?

**Rails version**: 4.2.4

**Ruby version**: 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db` folder was removed and that causes all issues with *pending* migration.

*Way to do is:*

1) Remove project folder

2) With **SourceTree** `clone` the project

3) Run `rake db:migrate` to migrate all tables